# get the event when accesing cognos report thru a link

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cognos

I have a java function that performs an action on a cognos report after load (it resizes an iframe within the report) so I wrote in the iframe specification `onload="resize();` it works perfect when i run the report but when i access the report from a link it doesn't  work. it seems that the load event doesn't occur so I want to get some event after the page loads to fire the function 
any thoughts?

here is my code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function resize()
    {
      var ocr2=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[2].contentWindow.cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_");
        document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].height=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentWindow.document.getElementById("CVReport" + ocr2._io.getId()).scrollHeight+20;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What's "default action" for report? Run or View?

Comment: the default action is run